# How can I limit the number of images shown per page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a certain number of images that are displaying per page. I want to set a maximum limit for the number of images shown on any page, for example setting a property such that no more than eight are shown. I've written this logic in PHP but I'm still seeing all images showing on any given page, ignoring any limit I set. The code:

```
$counter = 0;

foreach ($device as $value) {
  $entry = $value;
  echo "<head>";
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
           'window.setInterval(function() { ',
           "document.getElementById('$counter').src='/latimage.php?&dev=$entry&random='+new Date().getTime();",
           '},1000)',
       '</script>';
echo "</head>";
echo "<body onLoad='setTimeout('refresh()',1000)'>";
echo "<td>$entry<img id= '$counter'  width='100%'  height='auto'></img></td>";

$counter = $counter + 1;

if ($counter == 4 || $counter == 8) {
    echo " <tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your php is a mess, you know that right? And the question is not very clear. Please elaborate

Comment: please add more details . . [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could use `$counter` and check `if($counter < 8)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `$_GET['variable']`;

Something like this,

```
if(isset($_GET['last_image'])) {
  $last_image = $_GET['last_image'];
}
else {
  $last_image = 0;
}

$device[] = //however you get the images

$size_of_array = count($device);

for ($counter = $last_image; $counter < $counter + 8 && $counter < $size_of_array; $counter++) {
  $entry = $device[$counter];
  echo "<head>";
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
           'window.setInterval(function() { ',
           "document.getElementById('$counter').src='/latimage.php?&dev=$entry&random='+new Date().getTime();",
           '},1000)',
       '</script>';
  echo "</head>";
  echo "<body onLoad='setTimeout('refresh()',1000)'>";
  echo "<td>$entry<img id= '$counter'  width='100%'  height='auto'></img></td>";

}
```

Then next button

```
echo '<a href="myurl.com?last_image='. $counter .'">Next</a>';
```

This is the basic idea behind a pagination.

Comment: Do you want to load the other 8 images on a new html page?

Comment: yes... i wnt to show the next 8 image ,when i click any next button...$ device are the inage ..wgich are in array]

Comment: How do you get the images into the $device array? Are the image URLs in a database or did you hardcode the images array?

Comment: all the images are in folder ,, i read it. and keep in device[ ]

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to fetch only 8 images from database instead of fetching all images at once.Use pagination to set limit and offset for each page.

Comment: all are in array ..it may vary.

Comment: you want to paginate your images from array correct? please clarify the $device array will contain the same img data on every next button click?

Comment: i want to  specify you......i have folder which contains the image , $device contains the folder names and images are inside the folder  , in the java script part the images are loaded . but i want 8 image per page means,i want to show 8 folder. if there are more than 8 folder .when i click a button it should go to next page,this page should contain also 8 image,if more than 8 ,it go next .like that

Comment: so can do something like this:-

Comment: so can do something like this:- www.example.com?page=1 get page number via $pg = $_GET['page'] then process your array using forloop like  $index = $pg * 8; for($i=0;$i<(8);$i++){ echo $device[$index+$i]; }.